# Class object print in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, is it possible to print the whole object with properties?  (Here I don't know how many variables are declared in my parent class.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the LRM does not mention it, some simulators will allow you do use `$display("%p", object_handle);`.

This will most likely be a shallow print of your object, meaning that it will not print any class objects contained by your object. It also does not allow you to format individual properties, such as radix. For these reasons, you should only use this for quick debugging.

Most methodologies, like the UVM, require you to provide a set of virtual methods, such as  convert2string() or print() in all your classes. This way you call `super.print()` in your class's print() method to print all the properties in the base class, and you can class `property_handle.print()` to print all the members of a contained class.